# Borrowed value does not live long enough for `AsRef` result even if its `self` lives long enough

Tags: generics, rust, traits, lifetime

I have a struct that wraps some functionality around a slice:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

struct SliceWrapper<'a, T: Debug + Copy + 'a> {
    slice: &'a [T],
    pos: usize,
}
```

I want to implement the `From` trait for each element that supports `AsRef<T: Debug + Copy + 'a>` like this:

```
impl<'a, T: Debug + Copy + 'a, R: AsRef<[T]> + 'a> From<R> for SliceWrapper<'a, T> {
    fn from(slice: R) -> Self {
        Self {
            slice: slice.as_ref(),
            pos: 0,
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0597]: `slice` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:11:20
   |
11 |             slice: slice.as_ref(),
   |                    ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
14 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 8:6...
  --> src/lib.rs:8:6
   |
8  | impl<'a, T: Debug + Copy + 'a, R: AsRef<[T]> + 'a> From<R> for SliceWrapper<'a, T> {
   |      ^^
```

I don't understand this because I say that `R` (`slice`) must live as long as my `SliceWrapper` – and as far as I understand it, `AsRef<_>` inherits the lifetime from it's `self` (`slice`)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full error message on nightly states quite clearly what's happening here. You move `slice` into the function `from()`, then borrow it using `as_ref()`, and then it gets dropped at the end of the scope:

```
8  | impl<'a, T: Debug + Copy + 'a, R: AsRef<[T]> + 'a> From<R> for SliceWrapper<'a, T> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
9  |     fn from(slice: R) -> Self {
10 |         Self{ slice: slice.as_ref(), pos: 0 }
   |                      ^^^^^---------
   |                      |
   |                      borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                      argument requires that `slice` is borrowed for `'a`
11 |     }
   |     - `slice` dropped here while still borrowed
```

You are trying to create a borrow that lives for the lifetime `'a`, but the owner you are borrowing from, `slice`, does not live long enough.

The `From` trait does not seem to be a good fit for this use case. The idea of that trait is to move ownership of some data to a new type, but your `SliceWrapper` does not take ownership. I suggest writing a custom constructor instead that takes `R` by reference.

Comment: Ah damn, because `R` (and it's slice) are dropped when `from` returns, whereas `SliceWrapper` is supposed to live afterwards... 

Comment: That error isn't special to nightly; Rust 1.30 has the exact same one.

Comment: Yeah; the problem message was clear – I just didn’t get it. Genetics confuse me sometimes 

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the conversion to reference arguments, and then you have a nice way to express the borrowing you need — lifetime is taken from the input reference:

```
impl<'a, T, R> From<&'a R> for SliceWrapper<'a, T>
where
    T: Debug + Copy + 'a,
    R: AsRef<[T]>
{
    fn from(slice: &'a R) -> Self {
        Self {
            slice: slice.as_ref(),
            pos: 0,
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can follow your original reasoning.
You have AsRef giving you: `&'x self -> &'x [T]` for any `'x` and you input a `&'a R` into that, so you get a`&'a [T]` out.

Reference taking `From` sometimes exist, I think it's especially appropriate in reference-to-reference-like conversions. An example in std is `impl<'a> From<&'a str> for Cow<'a, str>`