# How can I decouple lifetimes from the AsRef wrapper?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to build a temporary wrapper class for `&[u8]` data that allows callers to extract the data with its original lifetime, not with the temporary wrapper lifetime.

If using `&[u8]` directly, this works:
[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=14b2dfb211384c118c3c40e3dfdb2013):

```rust
struct Wrapper1<'a> {
    data: &'a [u8],
}

impl<'a> Wrapper1<'a> {
    // In the return value, we return lifetime 'a, not the lifetime of the wrapper
    pub fn get(&self) -> &'a [u8] {
        &self.data[2..]
    }
}

fn func(data: &[u8]) -> &[u8] {
    let wrapper = Wrapper1 { data };
    // Note that we can return wrapper.get() even though Wrapper1 goes out of scope
    wrapper.get()
}

fn main() {
    let data = vec![5; 10];
    println!("{:?}", func(&data));
}
```

Now I want to do the same while abstracting over mutability, i.e. instead of working with `&[u8]`, I need to work with `AsRef<[u8]>` and `AsMut<[u8]>`. I've tried the following, but it doesn't work. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=59c396666d1523bc97ce00a884498d7c):

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Wrapper2<'a, S: 'a + AsRef<[u8]>> {
    data: S,
    _p: PhantomData<&'a S>,
}

impl<'a, S: 'a + AsRef<[u8]>> Wrapper2<'a, S> {
    pub fn get<'b>(&'b self) -> &'a [u8] {
        &self.data.as_ref()[2..]
    }
}

fn func(data: &[u8]) -> &[u8] {
    let wrapper = Wrapper2 {
        data,
        _p: PhantomData,
    };
    wrapper.get()
}

fn main() {
    let data = vec![5; 10];
    println!("{:?}", func(&data));
}
```

The error message:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:10:20
   |
10 |         &self.data.as_ref()[2..]
   |                    ^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'b` as defined on the method body at 9:16...
  --> src/main.rs:9:16
   |
9  |     pub fn get<'b>(&'b self) -> &'a [u8] {
   |                ^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:10:10
   |
10 |         &self.data.as_ref()[2..]
   |          ^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 8:6...
  --> src/main.rs:8:6
   |
8  | impl<'a, S: 'a + AsRef<[u8]>> Wrapper2<'a, S> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:10:9
   |
10 |         &self.data.as_ref()[2..]
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It can't find a good lifetime for the return of `Wrapper2::get()` because it requires it to outlive the lifetime of `&self`.

Is there any way to decouple it from the `wrapper` lifetime like I did in the `&[u8]` example above?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How do I specify the lifetime of an AsRef?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48734211/155423); [How to use the lifetime on AsRef](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32062866/155423); [Borrowed value does not live long enough for `AsRef` result even if its `self` lives long enough](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53437716/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: TL;DR — You cannot "decouple lifetimes" from `AsRef` because the lifetime associations are **part of the trait itself**. You can't change that any more than you can "decouple" the types from a function.

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks. Is there some different way to implement what I want? I tried storing the AsRef by reference to be able to directly specify its lifetime, but that still doesn't work: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=221e136bddcaf6886510a67b43f6903e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I understand the situation much better now. The issue is that `S: AsRef<[u8]>` doesn't only allow `S` to be reference types like `&[u8]` or `&mut [u8]`, but it could also be an object like `Vec<u8>`. And while for references you could argue that there should be a way to extend their lifetime beyond the `Wrapper` lifetime, for `Vec<u8>`, it obviously doesn't make sense since the `Vec<u8>` dies with the `wrapper`.

I've come up with two possible solutions:

#### 1. Don't extend the reference lifetimes, but allow a way to extract the inner object instead.

This allows the return statement in `func` as posed in the question.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=75ba8c81a1f3947c114caee33d8a4d57)

```rust
struct Wrapper2<S: AsRef<[u8]>> {
    data: S,
}

impl<S: AsRef<[u8]>> Wrapper2<S> {
    pub fn get(&self) -> &[u8] {
        &self.data.as_ref()[2..]
    }
    
    pub fn extract(self) -> S {
        // but note that we can only return the full data,
        // not a subset like get() or get_mut() would be doing
        self.data
    }
}

impl<S: AsRef<[u8]> + AsMut<[u8]>> Wrapper2<S> {
    pub fn get_mut(&mut self) -> &mut [u8] {
        &mut self.data.as_mut()[2..]
    }
}

fn func(data: &[u8]) -> &[u8] {
    let wrapper = Wrapper2 { data };
    let _g = wrapper.get();
    wrapper.extract()
}

fn func_mut(data: &mut [u8]) -> &mut [u8] {
    let mut wrapper = Wrapper2 { data };
    let _g = wrapper.get_mut();
    wrapper.extract()
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![5; 10];
    println!("{:?}", func(&data));
    println!("{:?}", func_mut(&mut data));
}
```

#### 2. Explicitly restrict the types to `&[u8]` and `&mut [u8]`

This means we're not using `AsRef` anymore, `Vec` is out of the picture and we know that we actually have a reference. In this case, the lifetime extension works correctly for the `&[u8]` case, i.e. we can get an `&[u8]` reference out of the wrapper and the reference will survive the wrapper. For `&mut [u8]`, we'd still need the `extract` function as in option 1 unfortunately.

This solution still fulfills the "abstracting over mutability" goal the question mentioned as the reason for introducing `AsRef` / `AsMut`, it just does it without those traits.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a66f689ac71c44bce4235e856cdc1fa8)

```rust
struct Wrapper2<S> {
    data: S,
}

impl <'a> Wrapper2<&'a [u8]> {
    fn get(&self) -> &'a [u8] {
        &self.data[2..]
    }
}

impl <'a> Wrapper2<&'a mut [u8]> {
    fn get_mut(&mut self) -> &mut [u8] {
        &mut self.data[2..]
    }
    
    fn extract(self) -> &'a mut [u8] {
        &mut self.data[2..]
    }
}

fn func(data: &[u8]) -> &[u8] {
    let wrapper = Wrapper2 { data };
    wrapper.get()
}

fn func_mut(data: &mut [u8]) -> &mut [u8] {
    let mut wrapper = Wrapper2 { data };
    let _a = wrapper.get_mut();
    let _b = wrapper.get_mut();
    wrapper.extract()
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![5; 10];
    println!("{:?}", func(&data));
    println!("{:?}", func_mut(&mut data));
}
```